# Tangent plane and normal

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I need to find the tangent plane and a unit normal vector to
$
r(u,v)=((2+\cos(u))\cos(v),(2+\cos(u))\sin(v),\sin(u))$ at  $(2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) $.

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}=(-\sin(u)\cos(v),-\sin(u)\sin(v),\cos(u) )  $

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}=(-\sin(v)(2+\cos(u) ), (2+\cos(u) )\cos(v), 0)  $

At the point given corresponding $"\theta"=u=\frac{\pi}{4} , "\phi"=v=0.$
So evaluating partial derivatives at $(2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}), $i.e. $ u=\pi /4,v=0 $.
gives the equation:

$p(h,k)= \begin{pmatrix} 2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix} +h\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix} +k\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ Which I think is right.

Now to find the unit normal I need $ \frac{\partial r}{\partial u} \times\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}$ then divide by magnitude which gives a horrible expression. Instead I just evaluated 
$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix} \times\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{2}} -0.5)i+(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{2}} -0.5)k$

Is this correct? Finding the unit normal is also quite a nasty fraction which alters my results..

Comment: Well, does the dot-product of your cross-product give zero against its inputs? This is always an easy check. Yep. I think the cross product is correct, the partials I have not checked yet.

Comment: Hmm yes , the normal dotted with the given point gives 0. So I simply divide by the magnitude now and done? It does not look like a nice value, although it must not. I was just wondering if there is some way to make it simpler which I possibly missed.

Comment: at first glance it doesn't look nice, but notice the components of $x$ and $z$ are the same hence the normalization is not too bad. A nice trick to know: if $\vec{A} = k\vec{B}$ then $\hat{A} = \hat{B}$ provided $k>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\vec{N} = \langle -\sqrt{2}-1/2, 0 , -\sqrt{2}-1/2 \rangle$ normalized is just the same as normalizing $\vec{M} = \langle -a,0,-a \rangle$ hence $\hat{N} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle -1,0,-1 \rangle$. As a check, $\hat{N}$ is orthogonal to your coordinate tangents $\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial v}$.